# Website for finding Hypernyms

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of questions on this Stack Exchange asking "What is a hypernym for ___ and ___". Is there somewhere you can enter a list of words and it will suggest hypernyms?

*This question will likely become the dead-end for this search until one is made. I can't believe there isn't one already!*

Comment: Not sure this is the right site to ask such questions. Check [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/hypernym#relate). It gives hypernyms under "relate".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/)

gives all sorts of semantic relations for a word, including hypernyms and hyponyms.

For example,

the hypernyms for 'lie' are

> [falsehood, falsity, untruth](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&s=lie&i=6&h=11000000000000000#c)

If you want to find the lest common hypernym of two words, which is often the desired end of these questions, you may have to do some clicking around on both words separately.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

> https://www.powerthesaurus.org/100_examples_of_hypernyms

The following quotations are from ThoughtCo.com, and they give good information about hypernyms:

> **Etymology**: from the Greek, "extra" + "name"
>
> **Examples and Observations:**
>
> "[A] hypernym is a broad, superordinate label that applies to many members of a set, while the members themselves are the hyponyms.
> "Hyponymy is a hierarchical relationship, and it may consist of a
> number of levels. For example, dog is a hyponym of animal, but it is
> also the hypernym of poodle, alsatian, chihuahua, terrier, beagle and
> so on."
>
> **(Jan McAllister and James E. Miller, Introductory Linguistics for Speech and Language Therapy Practice. Wiley-Blackwell, 2013)**
>
> "A hypernym is a word with a general meaning that has basically the same meaning of a more specific word. For example, dog is a
> hypernym, while collie and chihuahua are more specific subordinate
> terms. The hypernym tends to be a basic-level category that is used by
> speakers with high frequency; speakers usually refer to collies and
> chihuahuas as dogs, rather than using the subordinate terms, which are
> consequently of relatively low frequency."
>
> **(Laurie Beth Feldman, Morphological Aspects of Language Processing. Lawrence Erlbaum, 1995)**
>
> "The foot of footstep narrows down the type of step being expressed to the step made by a foot. A footstep is a kind of step;
> or, in more technical terms, footstep is a hyponym, or subtype, of
> step, and step is a hypernym, or supertype, of footstep. . . .
> Doorstep is also a hyponym of step, and step is a hypernym of
> doorstep."
>
> (Keith M. Denning, Brett Kessler, and William Ronald Leben, English
> Vocabulary Elements. Oxford University Press, 2007) Hypernyms,
> Hyponyms, and Connotations
>
> "Hyponyms are more likely to carry strong connotations than hypernyms, though this is not an invariable rule. The word 'animal'
> can carry negative connotations in metaphors such as 'He behaved like
> an animal.' However, more specific connotations can be carried by the
> use of more specific words. 'He ate like a pig.' 'You rat!' 'She's a
> bitch.'"
>
> **(Maggie Bowring et al., Working with Texts: A Core Introduction to Language Analysis. Routledge, 1997)** A Method of Definition
>
> "The most illuminating way of defining a lexeme is to provide a hypernym along with various distinguishing features—an approach to
> definition whose history can be traced back to Aristotle. For example,
> a majorette is 'a girl' (the hypernym) 'who twirls a baton and
> accompanies a marching band.' It is usually possible to trace a
> hierarchical path through a dictionary, following the hypernyms as
> they become increasingly abstract until we arrive at such general
> notions (essence, being, existence) that clear sense-relations between
> the lexemes no longer exist."
>
> **(David Crystal, The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language. Cambridge University Press, 2003)**